# How to trace which file causes a syntax error?

Tags: scons

I don't exactly know what I did, but seems like I broke my build system.

```
$ scons install
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
File "<string>", line 1

I_���.�K
        H�4����Ǐ��U)�f���R�f���ў�U)�f���R�f���ў�

   ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The unprintable characters are intended.

The bad thing is: Even resetting on a "known as working" version does not help, as well as using the options like `--debug=stacktrace`. My version control system (mercurial) does not show changes in the `SCons` files and I don't know how to proceed. Any hints how to make mercurial print the names of the files it's working on to find out what's happening?

My next step would be to make a new clone of the project (which hopefully builds), but I'm curious what's wrong here.

**UPDATE**

The problem disappeared when I updated to Ubuntu 12.04. "Disappeared" means in this case, that suddenly I've been able to execute the `scons --clean` command after which I was able to rebuild my project again. Sadly I cannot reproduce the error so that finally I don't know what caused it because it worked for several months and none of my colleagues had such a strange error before.

This is an excerpt of my script:

```
vars = Variables( "variables.cache" )
vars.Add( "CXX", "use this c++ compiler", "/usr/bin/g++" )
# (other stuff added to vars)

env = Environment( variables = vars )  # <-- this line caused the error
```

In the trouble fixing this I got the impression that after updating, Python was able to give me a better error message and the message was (trying to remember it) that `vars` is in some way invalid. So maybe the problem was in `variables.cache`, I don't know. Maybe I should just have deleted this file (which I did not) to get rid of the error.

Comment: Why are the unprintable characters intended?

Comment: Sorry for finding no better words. I mean: They showed up this way in terminal, there were no typing mistakes made by me here on SO which hide a helpful code line. Looks like scons tried to parse a binary file or some such?

Answer (score 1):

Try executing scons with warnings, as follows:

```
# scons --warn=all
```

If this doesnt help, you could try a more old-school approach and put some print statements in the SConstruct to see whats happening and when/where the problem occurs.

You could also try cleaning the entire project and removing/renaming the .sconsdb.lite in the root project.

UPDATE:

I recently had a problem because the version of Python was changed from 2.6 to 2.7 and the error handling changed completely. So, try putting a python try/except block around everything (or at least the strategic parts) in your SConstruct and print the exceptions (if any) that are thrown.

If none of these work, try posting the SConstruct here.

Code example from my `SConstruct` demonstrating how I found my error with a Python try/except block. The BuildError exception gave me a stack trace. There are more Exceptions that you can "catch".

```
...
try:
    SConscript(
        os.path.join(moduleDir, 'SConscript'),                        # sub-directory SConscript to load
        variant_dir = '#%s' % os.path.join(env['variantDir'], dir),   # path relative to this script where to put built files
        exports = ['env'],                                         # which variables to export to sub-directory build
        duplicate = 0)                                             # dont duplicate source files in variant_dir
except SCons.Errors.BuildError as be:
    print "*** BuildError exception processing module: %s, %s" % (moduleDir, be.__str__())
    raise
except:
    print "*** Unhandled exception processing module: %s" % moduleDir
    raise
```

Comment: Thanks for your support! The project is pretty huge (several subdirectories and therefore SConcripts) and the line which "causes" the error is like `env = Environment(var=vars)` or some such, I don't have it here at the moment (found out by `print "foo"` debugging). I'll definitely try at wednesday or tomorrow!

Comment: Well, nothing really works ... I know the line, but as I changed nothing manually, it must be an inconsistency with a generated file or some such. I can't clean, I can't do anything involving the `scons` command because it fails with the `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @wal-o-mat, I know you said the project is huge, but can you at least post the related part of the SConstruct/SConscript? You may consider posting it to ideone.com if its big.

Comment: @wal-o-mat, glad to hear its working again. Sounds like the variables.cache file was indeed the problem. Did you every try putting in a try/except block? That should have given more info.

Comment: I tired `print 'foo'` before and after the suspect blocks/lines, no `try/catch`. But as you can see: The thrown and uncaught `SyntaxError` gave me no readable clue, usually it prints the wrong code line or some such.

Comment: @wal-o-mat, I updated my answer with the try/except block I used. This probably would have helped, since you could probably have print out the stack trace.